# Return a column that displays the last known value (MAX DateTime) from a record table for each row by ID - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, maxdate

I know similar questions have been asked before and I'll include some links at the bottom, but can't work it out for my query.

I want to calculate 2 columns in a view that return the last known status (status A and status B) of a person for each row (status change by `DateTime`).

I have joined two record tables on `date_time` that contain information about a persons change in status over time. I want to know the latest value for status A for a person when status B changes and visa versa. For example, when a person's status changes from Hungry to Sad what was their latest (or current) StatusB (Active?).

My current query returns a table:

| DateTime | ID | StatusA_Old | StatusA_New | StatusB_Old | StatusB_New |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-01 23:57:20.000 | 1001 | NULL | Hungry | NULL | Active |
| 2021-02-02 23:57:20.000 | 1002 | NULL | Sad | NULL | Active |
| 2021-02-03 23:57:20.000 | 1001 | Hungry | Happy | NULL | NULL |
| 2021-02-04 23:57:20.000 | 1002 | NULL | NULL | Active | Inactive |

I want to return a table:

| DateTime | ID | StatusA_Old | StatusA_New | *StatusA_Current* | StatusB_Old | StatusB_New | *StatusB_Current* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-01 23:57:20.000 | 1001 | NULL | Hungry | Hungry | NULL | Active | Active |
| 2021-02-02 23:57:20.000 | 1002 | NULL | Sad | Sad | NULL | Active | Active |
| 2021-02-03 23:57:20.000 | 1001 | Hungry | Happy | Happy | NULL | NULL | Active |
| 2021-02-04 23:57:20.000 | 1002 | NULL | NULL | Sad | Active | Inactive | Inactive |

What have I tried?

I've had about 7 attempts at using subqueries and/or joining the table back on it's self to return the value of StatusA_New/StatusB_New at the MAX(DateTime) of the two original tables.

The closest I've go is probably this:

```
WITH T AS 
(
    SELECT 
        A.DateTime, A.ID, A.StatusA_New
    FROM A
)
SELECT 
    A.DateTime, A.ID, A.StatusA_Old, 
    A.StatusB_New, T.StatusA_New AS StatusA_Current
FROM 
    A
LEFT JOIN 
    T ON (A.DateTime <= T.DateTime) AND (A.ID = T.ID)
```

Keeping in mind that my current query does not even look at Status changes in B and does not yet deal with the joined DateTime table shown in the example tables.

The joined Table AB uses the following query:

```
/*example tables*/
create table A
(
    A_DateTime datetime,
    ID varchar(10),
    StatusA_Old varchar(10),
    StatusA_New varchar(10)
)

create table B
(
    B_DateTime datetime,
    ID varchar(10),
    StatusB_Old varchar(10),
    StatusB_New varchar(10)
)

insert into A values
('2021-02-01 23:57:20.000', 1001, NULL, 'Hungry'),
('2021-02-02 23:57:20.000', 1002, NULL, 'Sad'),
('2021-02-03 23:57:20.000', 1001, 'Hungry', 'Happy')

insert into B values
('2021-02-01 23:57:20.000', 1001, NULL, 'Active'),
('2021-02-02 23:57:20.000', 1002, NULL, 'Active'),
('2021-02-04 23:57:20.000', 1002, 'Active', 'Inactive')

SELECT  
     CASE 
        WHEN A.A_DateTime IS NULL THEN B.B_DateTime
        ELSE A.A_DateTime
     END AS DateTime,
     CASE 
        WHEN A.ID IS NULL THEN B.ID
        ELSE A.ID
     END AS ID,
     StatusA_Old, StatusA_New, 
     StatusB_Old, StatusB_New
FROM  
    A
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    B ON A.A_DateTime = B.B_DateTime
```

Similar questions:

- [Retrieve last known value for each column of a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246242/retrieve-last-known-value-for-each-column-of-a-row)
- [SQL: Select the last record for each day given datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62336768/sql-select-the-last-record-for-each-day-given-datetime)
- [Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql?rq=1)
- [SQL: How to fill empty cells with previous row value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465847/sql-how-to-fill-empty-cells-with-previous-row-value)
- Also might relate to this problem (as mentioned by another user) https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/last-non-null-puzzle

Comment: please ensure sample data provided matches with the current query result and expected result posted

Comment: Sorry. Fixed and tested it. should be right now.

Comment: What is the logic for `StatusA_Current` and `StatusB_Current` ?

Comment: StatusA_Current = The last known value of StatusA_New
I don't know the specific logic. Maybe... StatusA_Current = StatusA_New WHEN DateTime <= StatusA_New? Although I don't think that's quite right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a CTE for existing query and then sub-query to get the latest `NOT NULL` value from the `cte`

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT  COALESCE(A.A_DateTime, B.B_DateTime)    AS DateTime
        ,COALESCE(A.ID, B.ID)           AS ID
        ,StatusA_Old
        ,StatusA_New
        ,StatusB_Old
        ,StatusB_New
    FROM  A
    FULL OUTER JOIN B
      ON    A.ID        = B.ID
      AND   A.A_DateTime    = B.B_DateTime
)
SELECT  *
    ,(SELECT TOP 1 x.StatusA_New 
        FROM    CTE x 
        WHERE   x.ID = c.ID 
        AND x.DateTime <= c.DateTime 
        AND x.StatusA_New IS NOT NULL 
        ORDER BY x.DateTime DESC) AS StatusA_Current
    ,(SELECT TOP 1 x.StatusB_New 
        FROM    CTE x 
        WHERE   x.ID = c.ID 
        AND x.DateTime <= c.DateTime 
        AND x.StatusB_New IS NOT NULL 
        ORDER BY x.DateTime DESC) AS StatusB_Current
FROM    CTE c
ORDER BY [DateTime]
```