# SQL: "End-of-day" select

Tags: sql, datetime-format

I have a table, which contains some data with datetime in the below format (I'm using Dremio). For all columns in the table, I am trying to select only the last entry for a given day, e.g. for date 2023-07-18, row with time 10:30:23.537.

| Date_and_time | Parameter |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-07-31 09:37:43.143 | 1 |
| 2023-07-18 10:30:23.537 | 2 |
| 2023-07-18 10:29:55.148 | 3 |
| 2023-07-10 09:43:32.187 | 4 |
| 2023-07-10 09:43:05.171 | 5 |
| 2023-07-10 09:42:36.498 | 6 |

I have tried the solution proposed in [SQL: Select the last record for each day given datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62336768/sql-select-the-last-record-for-each-day-given-datetime).

I removed the DATE parameter from the above example as it was giving errors.

```
SELECT t1.* FROM t1

INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Date_and_time AS Date_time, MAX(Date_and_time) AS Date_time_end
    FROM t1
    GROUP BY Date_and_time
) t2
    ON t2.Date_time = t1.Date_and_time AND
       t2.Date_time_end = t1.Date_and_time
ORDER BY
    t1.Date_and_time;
```

Unfortunately, that has not given results as all rows were included in the result table.

Comment: What is your RDBMS? In your first join condition ON ...., you should convert (truncate) Date_and_time  to Date only (day/month/year without hour...) to get result for each date (as in answer in your linked question)

Comment: @PhamX.Bach Thanks! I'm using Dremio. Once I try to truncate Date_and_time I get an error _"Failure parsing the query"_ (= is underlined red in the line where I use DATE(t1.Date_and_time)). Any ideas why would this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
SELECT t2.castdate,
       t1.parameter
FROM table1 t1
JOIN
  (SELECT CAST(Date_and_time AS DATE) AS 'castdate',
          max(Date_and_time) AS 'Date_and_time'
   FROM table1
   GROUP BY castdate) t2 ON t1.Date_and_time = t2.Date_and_time
```

Query results in

| castdate | parameter |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-07-31 | 1 |
| 2023-07-18 | 2 |
| 2023-07-10 | 4 |

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad the issue is resolved!

Answer (score 0):

This might help you :

```
select * from table where date(Date_and_time)='2023-07-18' order by Date_and_time desc limit 1
```